# Finding equation of tangent of a vector

Tags: vector-spaces, tangent-spaces

hi guys and thanks in advance. I encounter this problem 21 and i couldnt solve it. my answer is so wrong.can anyone guide me on this?[image: ![This is the question sheet]

[image: This is my attempt]

Comment: To get  $(1,1,0)$  you must compute $\mathbf{r}(1)$.

Comment: Your derivative and unit vector are Ok.

Comment: hi hector and thanks for your help, my i know why do i need to do r(1) and isit apply for all question?

Comment: Is not always $t=0$ or $t=1$.  The value of $t$ to have the given point $P$ depends on whats tour formula for $\mathbf{r}(t)$.

Comment: For isntance, for problem 23 the right value of $t$ is $\frac{\pi}{3}=60^{\circ}$

Comment: In the future, please take the time to enter your question and relevant context as text instead of pasting pictures of it. Images are neither searchable nor accessible to screen readers, nor do they show up in summaries. (Your question is basically blank in a summary.) You can find a quick reference for using MathJax to format mathematical expressions [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: hector, may i know how i can determine the value for r?

Comment: no problem , amd.